"ADODB.Recordset: Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal" Error for Existing Column
I'm trying to execute the following SQL Query:
DECLARE @Start DATETIME
SET @Start = DateAdd(Hour, -1,GetDate())
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#logTable') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #logTable
CREATE TABLE #logTable
(
       LogDate DATETIME,
       ProccessINfo SYSNAME,
       [Text] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO #logTable exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'longer than 15 seconds to complete', N'', @Start, N'9999-12-31', N'desc'
 
SELECT * FROM tempdb..#logTable

Using a simple VBScript that I have wrote:
   'MSSQLQuery.vbs

    Option Explicit
    
   'On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim objCN, objRS, strConnection, strSQLQuery
    
    Set objCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    strConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Trusted_Connection=TRUE;Server=WINDMSSQL01.dev;Database=master"
    
    strSQLQuery = "DECLARE @Start DATETIME " & _
                  "SET @Start = DateAdd(Hour, -1,GetDate()) " & _
                  "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#logTable') IS NOT NULL " & _
                  "DROP TABLE #logTable " & _
                  "CREATE TABLE #logTable " & _
                  "( " & _
                   "LogDate DATETIME, " & _
                   "ProccessINfo SYSNAME, " & _
                   "[Text] NVARCHAR(MAX) " & _
                  ") " & _
                  "INSERT INTO #logTable exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'longer than 15 seconds to complete', N'', @Start, N'9999-12-31', N'desc' " & _
                  "SELECT * FROM tempdb..#logTable;"
    
    objCN.Open strConnection
    Set objRS = objCN.Execute(strSQLQuery)
    
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
    
        WScript.Echo "SQL Server Connection OK, SQL Query Output:" & vbCrLf
        
        WScript.Echo objRS.Fields("LogDate")     
         
    Else
    
        WScript.Echo "SQL Server Connection Not OK."
        
    End If

The SQL Query above, returns three columns:

LogDate
ProccessINfo
Text

The VBScript is successfully executing the SQL Query,
But when I'm trying to print one of three columns mentioned above (for example the "LogDate" column), I'm receiving the following error message:

MSSQLQuery.vbs(32, 2) ADODB.Recordset: Item cannot be
found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or
ordinal.

Which does not make sense, as I can see the column in the SQL Query results via the SSMS:


Uh, why vbscript. I think perhaps you need SET NOCOUNT ON at the start.

@siggemannen it's not VBScript it's ADODB that causes that behaviour.

Yeah, but who writes in vbscript in 2024. It's even deprecated by ms by now!

This question is similar to: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed (Object is not closed). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@siggemannen yeah, it's 2024 so you'd believe this has probably been answered before.

@siggemannen, i don't think that learning is bowed to a year or technology, it is the drive the keep evolving in the fields that you are exploring, but i appreciate your response.

I agree in general, since I used to write in vbscript for 13 years in another life but time hasn't been good to it, there's a reason we're not still driving horsecarts

It could also be that the OP is of some age and has no desire to install something like Python or learn Powershell. Assume he/she does know VB6 (or  lower) going with VBS makes sense. It is sitting right there.

SQL Server returns a lot of ROWCOUNTs when you do other statements than SELECT, so it usually help to set SET NOCOUNT ON.
Also, you should loop your recordset, something like:
...
strSQLQuery = "SET NOCOUNT ON; DECLARE @Start DATETIME " & _
                  "SET @Start = DateAdd(Hour, -1,GetDate()) " & _
                  "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#logTable') IS NOT NULL " & _
                  "DROP TABLE #logTable " & _
                  "CREATE TABLE #logTable " & _
                  "( " & _
                   "LogDate DATETIME, " & _
                   "ProccessINfo SYSNAME, " & _
                   "[Text] NVARCHAR(MAX) " & _
                  ") " & _
                  "INSERT INTO #logTable exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'', N'', @Start, N'9999-12-31', N'desc' " & _
                  "SELECT * FROM tempdb..#logTable;"
    
    objCN.Open strConnection
    Set objRS = objCN.Execute(strSQLQuery)
    
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
    
        WScript.Echo "SQL Server Connection OK, SQL Query Output:" & vbCrLf
        while Not objRS.EOF    
            WScript.Echo objRS.Fields("LogDate")
        objRS.MoveNext
         wend
    Else
    
        WScript.Echo "SQL Server Connection Not OK."
        
    End If
...


Thanks, the use of "SET NOCOUNT ON" in the beginning of the SQL query has solved the problem, but I don't understand why. from Microsoft documentation "SET NOCOUNT ON;" is being explained as follow: "Stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set.", which honestly is not very clear to me, what his functionality, and how using it, solved my problem. can you please elaborate?

When you do things like INSERT etc, SQL Server generates row count messages which it sends to the client. Some libs turn these into fake RecordSets which you have to process by using some convoluted code until you get to the RecordSet you're interested in. SET NOCOUNT ON disables these messages from SQL server, so you don't have to bother with that and go straight to the recordset you're interested in
